# azure blob storage python 2.7

Tags: azure, python-2.7, azure-blob-storage

Hi I am using one application which runs fine in windows with python 2.7 , which is copying files to azure blob storage , same setup i am facing issue in linux/ubuntu setup when we try to import below packges:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
```

**Error :** ImportError: No module named parse

Can someone help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Use  the latest version via:

```
pip install azure-storage –upgrade
```

And also try with this

**1.** Uninstall azure-storage-blob using: pip uninstall azure-storage-blob.

**2.** Reinstall azure-storage-blob using: pip install azure-storage-blob.

For more details refer this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/232)

Comment: Still it doesn't work , tried both the steps.

Comment: which version of pip you are using?

Comment: i am using python 2.7 pip2 ==> pip version 8.1.1